# Merging two branches with Xcode

Tags: xcode, git, git-branch, git-merge

I am trying to merge two branches to gather in Xcode but can not seem to do it. 
The steps I take are the following.
SourceControl > Merge from branch > pick the branch I want to get the new code from > then hit merge.

What popup is a warning that states this:

```
The operation could not be performed because of one or more tree conflicts.
The files MyClient.xcscheme, xcschememanagement.plist, UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate, Pods-MyClient.xcscheme, SwiftyJSON.xcscheme, and xcschememanagement.plist had a tree conflict.
```

I am lost on what to do here. Thank you for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual advice is to fall back to the CLI (command-line), and do a `git status`

From there, you can resolve any conflict mentioned ([like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25357109/6309)), `git add`, and if a merge was indeed in progress, `git commit` to complete it.